# How to pick values of ambient, diffuse, specular for Phong Lighting?

Tags: lighting, reflection

I have the following code in python using the vedo package

```
mesh.lighting(style='plastic', ambient=None, diffuse=None, specular=None,
              specular_color=None, specular_power=None, metallicity=None, roughness=None)
```

I know that I need a combination for ambient, diffuse, specular value to creating phong lighting. How do I determine these values? And how do I know I have created phong lighting?

Answer (score 0):

From the manual:

- `style` : (str) preset style, options are [metallic, plastic, shiny,
  glossy, ambient, off]
- `ambient` : (float) ambient fraction of emission
  [0-1]
- `diffuse` : (float) emission of diffused light in fraction [0-1]
- `specular` : (float) fraction of reflected light [0-1]
- `specular_power` :
  (float) precision of reflection [1-100]
- `specular_color` : (color) color that is being reflected by the surface

Set the `ambient`/`diffuse`/`specular` parameters to increasing values one at a time and observe the effect. A Phong model requires a combination of the three components. Also play with `specular_power` and `specular_color`  (only relevant with nonzero specular).

I could not find any information on `metallicity` nor `roughness`. Have a try with values in range [0-1].

It is possible (likely) that the preset styles enforce predefined sets of parameter values, and to use your own the `off` mode is required.